# Select distinct field along others query while statement is done

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am trying select distinct records from mysql db. But i can't able to do this.

Here is the table:

```
id,  f2,      f3,         f4
1,   a1,      mytext,     t1
2,   a2,      mytext,     t2
3,   a2,      mytext,     t3
4,   a3,      mytext,     t4
5,   a1,      mytext,     t5
6,   a5,      mytext,     t6
```

I am trying to get the distinct f2 results:

```
id,  f2,       f3,         f4
3,   a2,      mytext,      t3
4,   a3,      mytext,      t4
5,   a1,      mytext,      t5
6,   a5,      mytext,      t6
```

Can give me What is the Exact SQL Query?

Comment: Are you sure your expected results are right? There's no row in the original table with `f2=a2` and `f4=t5`.

Comment: your accepted answer doesn't give the right result at all times. [click this link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65bfb/3)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IF you gave more info then the query could be more optmized and according to your requirements.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable GROUP BY f2
```

Comment: Here is one table only and need f3, f4 along distinct f2 resultset.

Comment: `select *` means to select all columns, including `f3` and `f4`.

Comment: @raheelshan How can you able to select all the records by grouping only f2 ? Your query is wrong

Comment: @Mari: unfortunately MySQL allows such a stupid thing. It will simply pick "random" values for the non-grouped columns

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT f2, MAX(f4) maxVal
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY f2
        ) b ON  a.f2 = b.f2 AND
                a.f4 = b.maxVAL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f80bc/2)

Comment: What do you meant by MAX(f4) ?

Comment: the subquery gets the maximum value of `f4` separately and the result of which will then be joined back again on the original table. see the example link, [see the difference between my answer and your accepted answer](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65bfb/3)

Answer (score 0):

if you really looking for `distinct`

then here your sql

```
      SELECT  distinct f2 ,id, f3, f4  FROM TableName
         group by f2
```

[**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f80bc/14)

edit :

this exactly what u want  [demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f80bc/3)

Comment: can you check your answer against expected answer. It's not what asked for

Comment: Actually here is needs distinct f2 only with others. Others records are exist or not is not matter. Just need distinct f2 along recordset/row(where staying f2).